# Help Solving recursive functions

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

If
$$
f(n,m,k) = 
\begin{cases}
n\cdot f(n-1,m,k+1) & \text{if } k = 0 \text{ or } k = 1 \\
(n+m)! & \text{if } k>m \\
n\cdot f(n-1,m,k+1) + m\cdot f(n,m-1,k-1) & \text{if } 1 < k \le m
\end{cases}
$$

Given that $$n > m$$
How can I prove that $$ \frac{f(n,m,0)}{(n+m)!} = \frac{n-m}{n+m} \text{ ?}$$

Comment: Bertrand's ballot theorem